# Is there a way to calculate bond energies using computational chemistry?

Tags: computational-chemistry, coordination-compounds

I'm currently trying to see if a particular set of ligands will react with a metal ion to form a complex. While I'm waiting for the wet lab results to arrive, my adviser suggested we look into computational chemistry to see if we can model the proposed structures theoretically.

Neither of us (or anyone in the department for that matter) have any experience in computational chemistry. I got my hands on a copy of Avogadro and GAMESS-US and have optimized the geometries of the complexes we think might arise. Is there a way to determine if the complexes would form? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to calculate bond energies using GAMESS?

Yes. You would normally model the bound and unbound states

$$\ce{ML_{n - 1} + L -> ML_{n}}$$

The [definition of bond energy](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/B/B00701.html) is based on the enthalpy of reaction in the gas phase ([thanks DSVA!](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86198/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-bond-energies-using-computational-chemistry#comment179274_86259)), so you would calculate it as follows:

$$\Delta H^\circ = H_{\ce{ML_{n}}} - (H_{\ce{ML_{n - 1}}} + H_{\ce{L}})\text{.}$$

---

While not strictly bond energy by definition, a value for the reaction Gibb's free energy might also be useful in some contexts:

$$\Delta G^\circ = G_{\ce{ML_{n}}} - (G_{\ce{ML_{n - 1}}} + G_{\ce{L}})\text{.}$$

This takes entropy into account.
For the calculation of Gibb's free energies, most codes calculate the molecular partition function from translational, rotational and vibrational contributions and get enthalpy and entropy from it.
Due to the vibrational contributions, you'll need to diagonalize the Hessian matrix of the system. **This will give you an association (minus dissociation) energy value**.
(You might take solvation into account through explicit/implicit solvation, use decent level of theory, validate/benchmark, etc.)
There are a lot of approximations and considerations in the process. More can be found [here](http://gaussian.com/thermo/) (some equations) and [here](http://molecularmodelingbasics.blogspot.com.br/2009/07/typical-set-of-gamess-calculations.html) (more practical).

Observe that

$$K = e^{- \frac{\Delta G^\circ}{R T}}$$

is the equilibrium constant associated with the process above, which is called the stability constant, formation constant or binding constant.
This is widely used to "measure the strength of the interaction between the reagents that come together to form a complex" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_constants_of_complexes)).
Bear in mind that $\Delta G^\circ$ goes inside an exponential, i.e., small errors in $\Delta G^\circ$ become (exponentially) large errors in $K$, so $\Delta G^\circ$ might be more useful in a computational context than $K$ itself.

---

> Is there a way to determine if the complexes would form?

This is complicated.

Your reaction might be too slow though, i.e., actual formation might depend on transition states. Furthermore, there might be faster processes in competition that you might miss.

Comment: Going back to this after a few months, how exactly do you get the Free Energy of the Metal? I understand modelling the Ligands and getting their SPE and Vibration Energies, but I'm not sure where to get the data on the metals.

Comment: You would get data from the complex and the complex minus a ligand (I edited the question to highlight it). You normally don't need the metal alone to do it for complexes.

Comment: Aren't bond energies usually defined as the difference in enthalpy rather than gibbs free energy? See: https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/B/B00701.html

Comment: Thanks @DSVA, you're right! I edited the answer to make this definition clearer.

Comment: Thanks @FelipeS.S.Schneider! So you're saying I get the energies of the ligands, multiplied by the coordination number and subtract that from the energy of the bound state and I'll get the enthalpy of formation?

Is there a way, then to measure the entropy of the system so I can find the Free Energy Change? Or would the enthalpy suffice to say if the reaction is feasible? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: [This](http://web.thu.edu.tw/ghliu/www/pdf/thermo.pdf) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy) might help.